# beautifulsoup find id given text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my `html`:

```
<div id="div:{c4b05d3c-dc70-409c-b28b-9cdb1157d346}{35}" style="position:absolute;left:624px;top:595px;width:624px">
   <p id="p:{c9c23667-929c-4ee2-be44-edc002db83b8}{145}" style="margin-top:5.5pt;margin-bottom:5.5pt">
    {blah}  data123
   </p>
  </div>
```

I want to find and return `p:{c9c23667-929c-4ee2-be44-edc002db83b8}{145}` by looking for the text `{blah}`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, use `re` module to match text with regex:

```
import re
soup.find('p', text = re.compile('blah'))['id']
# u'p:{c9c23667-929c-4ee2-be44-edc002db83b8}{145}'
```